# Adding a new tab to user in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal-7

How can I add a new tab to user profile. I want to add for instance New User Tab which will be visible by administrator and user itself (not others).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi friends thanks for helping me.... 
I done with under code

`function downloaded_menu(){
     $items['user/%user/downloaded'] = array(
    'title' => 'Downloaded',
    'page callback' => 'downloaded_content_page',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => 10,
  );
  return $items;
}`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create your own module, the code will look like this:

```
<?php
// Define callback for tab.
function user_tab_menu(){
    return array(
        'user/%/new_tab' => array(
            'title' => 'New tab',
            'page callback' => 'user_tab_page',
            'page arguments' => array(1),
            'access callback' => 'user_tab_access',
            'access arguments' => array(1),
            'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
        ),
    );
}

// Show the page
function user_tab_page($uid){
    return 'New tab';
}

// Check if user has permission, or views its own page
function user_tab_access($uid){
    return ($uid == $GLOBALS['user']->uid) || user_access('view user tabs');
}

// Define permission for administrators
function user_tab_perm(){
    return array(
        'view user tabs' => array(
            'title' => t('View user tabs'), 
            'description' => t('View user tabs'),
        ),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this through the views module without having to do custom coding.

Set up a new view page with path as 'user/%'
Set contextual filter as 'user:uid'

Set your page content as 'user' or 'fields' or whatever you want rendered. This is going to 'hijack' the standard drupal page into a views rendering.

Now you can add any amount of additional tabs by adding views pages and setting the path to 'user/%/path_of_your_tab'. Set the menu entry for each tab to 'menu tab' and 'user menu'

You can then set access permissions in views for each tab.

Comment: Yes, this would be great way to view things on a user's profile, but it won't allow you to edit things, it's not generic enough.